# Keep file descriptor open in fish shell

Tags: exec, file-descriptor, fish

In Fish there is no

```
exec 3<>file
```

like in bash.

Is there any curious workaround?

---

#### The problem

The idea is to open pipe to remote (or local) shell. In bash this looks like:

```
mkfifo srvin
exec <>stdin  ## keep pipe open
ssh $server -t bash <srvin
echo $command >srvin
echo $command2 >srvin
```

Without `exec` pipe will be closed after first `echo` and ssh will be stopped. The goal is to keep ssh-connection and be able to send commands and receive results. SSH is only for example, it also works with local bash, netcat, others.

Comment: What do you want to _do_? Is this for logging, or for locking a file, or just academic? There is no direct replacement, so what you should do depends on what you need it for.

Comment: added "the problem" paragraph

Answer (score 2):

There is no read-write redirection. If you only need read *or* write, you can wrap your code in a begin/end block and apply the redirection to it:

```sh
begin
    echo your code here
end 3<file   # or, end 3>file
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated question with problem description.